# std::map erase - pass iterator to wrong map

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, stdmap

Take this snippet of C++:

```
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m1;
    m1[1] = 2;

    std::map<int, int> m2;
    m2[3] = 4;
    m1.erase(m2.begin());

    return m2.size();
}
```

On godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/mJBszn

This feels like it must be undefined behaviour. Is that correct? If so, which part of the standard says so?

Comment: It should give undefined behavior. Because, in `m1.erase(m2.begin())` , `m2.begin()` pointing to a location which is invalid for `m1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This feels like it must be undefined behaviour. Is that correct?

Yes.

> If so, which part of the standard says so?

The standard slaps down this bit of silliness in **[associative.reqmts]** note 8. I am [citing n4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts#8) because it's what I have a link to and close to C++17. At this time C++20 is still too much of a moving target.

Diving down into **[tab:container.assoc.req]** we find three `erase` overloads that take iterators,

```
a.erase(q)
a.erase(r)
a.erase(q1, q2)
```

of which `a.erase(r)` is the one of interest to the asker.

The table only states what happens if the program behaves; however the preamble to this table states that

> `q` denotes a valid dereferenceable constant iterator to `a`, `r` denotes a valid dereferenceable iterator to `a`, [`q1`, `q2`) denotes a valid range of constant iterators in `a`

In other words, if the iterator `r` is not from `map` `a`, `a`'s `end` iterator, or has been invalidated or otherwise rendered undereferenceable, the contract is broken and the results have been left undefined.

I include `q`, `q1` and `q2` to show the rules are the same for a constant iterator and iterator ranges.

Answer (score 4):

This is all in reference to C++17.

Edit 2** I take back what I originally said, I just thread through part of the c++ standard and from a comment. In §26.2.6 the standard states for a.erase(r) in the context of associative containers is "If no such element exists, returns a.end()." However, the standard also states "r denotes a valid dereferenceable iterator to a"

Since this is not the case for m2.begin(), this is not in line with the standard, thus undefined behavior.

Comment: You found the right stuff, but [you have to look up a bit](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/associative.reqmts#8) In the notes before the table it says *q denotes a valid dereferenceable constant iterator to a, r denotes a valid dereferenceable iterator to a* and in this case we want `a.erase(r)` from the table.

Comment: The link is to a newer version of the Standard, mind you. [This should be closer to C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts#8)

Comment: @user4581301 Ah good catch. I must have gotten lost in the words. I take back my take back. Undefined behavior it is!

Comment: Update the answer and you'll have my upvote. Side note: Because the section numbers change frequently between drafts (not to mention between official releases), prefer to use the section tag, **[associative.reqmts]** in this case, so folk five years from now have a better chance of finding the right section in C++ 24 or whatever.